# Having Trouble with numpy.histogramdd

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create N-Dimensional histogram from 2D array which has complex values. I want to count the number of occurrences in real and imaginary parts of the array given the bins and store the result in a 3D array. It only runs for the first iteration when I hard code i=0 and remove the for loop. I have never used histograms in python before and I just cannot understand the error. The code is given below.

xsoft is defined as 2d array of complex type and I somehow compute bnd_edges by finding max, min values from xsoft and create edges to be given as bins.

```
xsoft = np.empty((M, MAX,), dtype=complex) # e.g has dims 4*100
xsoft[:] = np.nan

edges = np.linspace(-bnd_edges, bnd_edges, numbin)  #numbin=10  

pSOFT = np.empty((len(edges)-1, M, len(edges)-1))  # len(edges)= 10

pSOFT[:] = np.nan

for i in range(M):

   pSOFT[:, i, :], edges = np.histogramdd((xsoft[i, :].real, xsoft[i, :].imag), bins=(edges, edges))
```

The code results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File " ", line 194, in <module> 
    pSOFT[:, i, :], edges = np.histogramdd((xsoft[i, :].real, xsoft[i, :].imag), bins=(edges, edges))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in histogramdd
  File " " line 1066, in histogramdd
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `bins[0]` must be a scalar or 1d array

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is `type(bnd_edges)`? Is it a scalar (e.g. float type)?

Comment: Yes it is a scalar with type float (e.g 1.296**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are overriding the original definition of `edges` with the second return value of `histogramdd`.
Replace the last line in your code with this:

```
pSOFT[:, i, :], edges_i = np.histogramdd((xsoft[i, :].real, xsoft[i, :].imag), bins=(edges, edges))
```

Comment: Oh yes, That was such a lame mistake. The name for both edges should not have been the same. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Alveena that's ok. I just noticed that I wrote "overriding" instead of "overwriting" in my answer, so I also just made a lame mistake :)